# python regex to find alphanumeric string with at least one letter

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out the syntax for regular expression that would match 4 alphanumeric characters, where there is at least one letter. Each should be wrapped by: `>` and `<` but I wouldn't like to return the angle brackets.

For example when using `re.findall` on string `>ABCD<>1234<>ABC1<>ABC2` it should return `['ABCD', 'ABC1']`.

`1234` - doesn't have a letter

`ABC2` - is not wrapped with angle brackets

Comment: And what is your regex expression you made :/  ?

Comment: [`(?i)>((?=\d*[a-z])[a-z\d]{4})<`](https://regex101.com/r/oOHPvO/3) should work for you

Comment: The part I'm having problem is 'at least one letter' and 'not returning brackets'. Without those two requirements it's quite straightforward: `r'(>[A-Z0-9]{4}<)'` I'm not sure it's even possible with regex, is it?

Comment: You say you'd like to match `['ABCD', 'ABC4']` from your example string. But your example string does not contain "ABC4". Is this a typo? If not, please elaborate further on the business logic involved.

Comment: @Kevin - sorry for typo, I edited the post to correct it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this lookahead based regex in python with `findall`:

```
(?i)>((?=\d*[a-z])[a-z\d]{4})<
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oOHPvO/3/)

**Code:**

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r">((?=\d*[a-z])[a-z\d]{4})<", re.I)
>>> s = ">ABCD<>1234<>ABC1<>ABC2"
>>> print (regex.findall(s))
['ABCD', 'ABC1']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `re.I`: Enable ignore case modifier
- `>`: Match literal character `>`
- `(`: Start capture group

  - `(?=\d*[a-z])`: Lookahead to assert we have at least one letter after 0 or more digits
  - `[a-z\d]{4}`: Match 4 alphanumeric characters
- `)`: End capture group
- `<`: Match literal character `<`

Comment: wouldn't it be better to compile the regex and to add the incasitive flag as the 2nd arg instead of making the regex string longer?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Would you mind elaborating on the syntax?

Comment: @YannicHamann: Good idea, have added `re.compile` in the code.

Comment: @MJB: I have added detailed explanation of regex in my answer. Let me know which part is not clear and I will add more details.

Comment: @MJB: Click on the demo and read the right side.  It has a more verbose explanation.  Then read the regex docs for what doesn't make sense.  The key here is the lookahead assertion `(?=\d*[a-z])` (lookaheads start with `?=`).  It asserts something about the characters that follow without gobbling up any characters.

Comment: Thanks @StevenRumbalski for correcting me. I should get my eyes checked now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
sentence = ">ABCD<>1234<>ABC1<>ABC2"
pattern = "\>((?=[a-zA-Z])(.){4})\<"
m = [m[0] for m in re.findall(pattern, sentence)]
#outputs ['ABCD', 'ABC1']
```

Comment: Some explanation might be useful here